# Can't start Alice HTTP Inspector. Please add NavigatorKey to your application

Tags: http, flutter, dart, inspector, alice

navigatorKey has already been added to the code, still it shows error(red line) under the navigatorKey.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return WillPopScope(
navigatorKey: _alice.getNavigatorKey(),
child: Theme(
data: ThemeData(
brightness: Brightness.light,
primarySwatch: AppColor.appColor,
primaryColor: AppColor.white,
buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData().copyWith(
buttonColor: AppColor.appColor,
textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary),
fontFamily: "EncodeSans",
),
child: layout()),

onWillPop: () {
return handleBackPress();
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change navigatorKey to key:

you code must look like belew:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return WillPopScope(
key: _alice.getNavigatorKey(), // here i replace key with navigatorKey
child: Theme(
data: ThemeData(
brightness: Brightness.light,
primarySwatch: AppColor.appColor,
primaryColor: AppColor.white,
buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData().copyWith(
buttonColor: AppColor.appColor,
textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary),
fontFamily: "EncodeSans",
),
child: layout()),

onWillPop: () {
return handleBackPress();
});
}
```

Comment: Yes i add the key: _alice.getNavigatorKey(), , but still after click on the notificationshade  the page can't be  opened.

Comment: Still i can not open my notification shade,s result page when tap on it.

Comment: please share complete source code of this page to help you

Answer (score 0):

Use http package **http: any version**

1. **Create new class(APIConstant) and then use this code in the class**

```
  static Alice alice=Alice(
    showShareButton: true,
    showNotification: true,
  );
```

2. **Use this code in main.dart**

   `navigatorKey: APIConstant.alice.getNavigatorKey(),`
3. **Like this:**

`if (kDebugMode) APIConstant.alice.onHttpResponse(response, body: jsonEncode(sendOtpReq));`

```
  Future<SendOtpModels?> sendOtpApi(SendOtpReq  sendOtpReq) async {
    try {
      CustomLoader.showLoader("Please wait");
      final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(APIConstant.sendOtp),
        headers: APIConstant.authHeader,
        body: jsonEncode(sendOtpReq),
      );
      if (kDebugMode) APIConstant.alice.onHttpResponse(response, body: jsonEncode(sendOtpReq));

      const utf8Decoder = Utf8Decoder(allowMalformed: true);
      final decodedBytes = utf8Decoder.convert(response.bodyBytes);
      Map<String, dynamic> responseBody = json.decode(decodedBytes);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        CustomLoader.closeLoader();
        return SendOtpModels.fromJson(responseBody);
      }
    }
    on TimeoutException catch (e) {
      CustomLoader.closeLoader();
      CustomLoader.showToast(e.message.toString());
    }  catch (e) {
      CustomLoader.closeLoader();
      CustomLoader.showToast(e.toString());
    }
    return null;
  }
```